# Trying to understand Intel Intrinsics Guide explanation for _mm256_permute2x128_si256

Tags: c++, simd, avx, avx2

I'm trying to understand _mm256_permute2x128_si256. Is all 256 bits of register a read into the case first then is the 256 bits of register b read into the case after? Or is every 32 bits read in interleaved between vector a and vector b? So which 32 bits of which vector is read in corresponding to which bit in imm8 in what order and how? Thanks!

```
DEFINE SELECT4(src1, src2, control) {
    CASE(control[1:0]) OF
    0:  tmp[127:0] := src1[127:0]
    1:  tmp[127:0] := src1[255:128]
    2:  tmp[127:0] := src2[127:0]
    3:  tmp[127:0] := src2[255:128]
    ESAC
    IF control[3]
        tmp[127:0] := 0
    FI
    RETURN tmp[127:0]
}
dst[127:0] := SELECT4(a[255:0], b[255:0], imm8[3:0])
dst[255:128] := SELECT4(a[255:0], b[255:0], imm8[7:4])
dst[MAX:256] := 0
```

Comment: `CASE(control[1:0]) OF` is to be read like `switch(control & 0x3) {` in C/C++ (but with an implicit `break` after each case). Where do you see 32bits in the pseudo code?

Comment: @chtz if src1 is a 256 bit vector isn't that represented in memory as one element for every 32 bits in the register?

Comment: @chtz How did you know to & the control with 0x3 in each switch case?

Answer (score 2):

It's a shuffle that selects two 128-bit lanes from the 4 total lanes of 2 input vectors.
The control integer operand has two 2-bit fields that each index one of 4 lanes.  You could look at it as concatenating both input vectors and then indexing into that 4-lane array.

Or if the high bit of the index nibble is set, it zeros that lane of the result.

There's nothing involving 32-bit granularity.  The pseudo-code from the intrinsics guide defines a helper function, and passes all 256 bits of each input to that helper function twice.  All the `[hi:lo]` ranges are in bits, not bytes.

Intel's asm documentation for the corresponding instructions ([`vperm2i128`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vperm2i128)) has more comprehensible pseudo-code that separates the zeroing:

```
CASE IMM8[1:0] of
    0: DEST[127:0]←SRC1[127:0]
    1: DEST[127:0]←SRC1[255:128]
    2: DEST[127:0]←SRC2[127:0]
    3: DEST[127:0]←SRC2[255:128]
ESAC

CASE IMM8[5:4] of
    0: DEST[255:128]←SRC1[127:0]
    1: DEST[255:128]←SRC1[255:128]
    2: DEST[255:128]←SRC2[127:0]
    3: DEST[255:128]←SRC2[255:128]
ESAC

IF (imm8[3])
    DEST[127:0] ← 0
FI
IF (imm8[7])
    DEST[255:128] ← 0
FI
```

Comment: If reading in a control value of 49 (0b0011 0b0001) is this read little endian as it looks currently or is it read big endian in reverse by the compiler as 0b0100 0b1100?

Comment: @artVandalay: It's 1 byte so there's no endianness in the normal sense.  The left-most bit is bit 7, the most significant.  (0 for `49 = 0x31 = 0b0011'0001`).  Bits [7:4] control the high lane of the destination (the ones that will be stored to a higher address by `_mm256_store...`). Intel's standard notation and diagrams for vectors put the highest element at the left, lining up with our standard place-value system for writing numbers.  [Convention for displaying vector registers](//stackoverflow.com/q/41351087) / [How does endianness work with SIMD registers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/24045102)

Comment: Hex is a useful notation for the control value because that splits it into the two 4-bit groups, and the useful values are 0..3 or anything with the high bit set (8 or higher).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Please see this website, it's more informative than Intel's documentation:

https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vperm2i128